# How to adjust height and width properly with jquery and css vh

Tags: jquery, css

I am just new to CSS3 and working with an existing code. Please check the below link.

http://tinyurl.com/lncfmd4 | userid - vts password - vts

My question is in **1920x1080** resolution the top bar height is 8vh and looking fine.

But using **1360x768** the top bar shrinks to smaller and menus not coming properly.

Below is the responsible JQuery which adjusting height and width, so is there any solution to this ?

```
function check_height(){
                var t = $('#thidden').val();
                var d = $('#dhidden').val();
                var r = $('#rhidden').val();
                var l = $('#lhidden').val();
                var w = $('.right_header').width();
                w = w+27;
                var h = $('.footer').height();
                h = h + 30;
                if(t==0 && d==0 && r==0 && l==0){
                    $(".right_header").animate({"margin-top":"0vw","margin-right":"0vw","height":"64vh","width":"12.25vw"},200);
                    $(".left_header").animate({"margin-top":"0vw","margin-left":"0vw","height":"64vh","width":"16.75vw"},200);
                    $(".footer").animate({"margin-bottom":"0vh","height":"30vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("nav").animate({"margin-top":"0vh","height":"8vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("#map-canvas").animate({"height":"64vh","width":"71vw","margin-left":"16.75vw","margin-top":"8vh"},200);
                    $("#r_controls").animate({"right":w+"px","top":"37%"},200);
                    $("#l_controls").animate({"left":"16.75vw","top":"37%"},200);
                    $("#t_controls").animate({"left":"50%","top":"8vh"},200);
                    $("#d_controls").animate({"left":"50%","bottom":h+"px"},200);
                }
                if(t==0 && d==0 && r==0 && l==1){
                    $(".right_header").animate({"margin-top":"0vw","margin-right":"0vw","height":"64vh","width":"12.25vw"},200);
                    $(".left_header").animate({"margin-top":"0vw","margin-left":"-16.75vw","height":"64vh","width":"16.75vw"},200);
                    $(".footer").animate({"margin-bottom":"0vh","height":"30vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("nav").animate({"margin-top":"0vh","height":"8vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("#map-canvas").animate({"height":"64vh","width":"87.75vw","margin-left":"0vw","margin-top":"8vh"},200);
                    $("#r_controls").animate({"right":w+"px","top":"37%"},200);
                    $("#l_controls").animate({"left":"0vw","top":"37%"},200);
                    $("#t_controls").animate({"left":"50%","top":"8vh"},200);
                    $("#d_controls").animate({"left":"50%","bottom":h+"px"},200);
                }

                if(t==0 && d==0 && r==1 && l==0){
                    $(".right_header").animate({"margin-top":"0vw","margin-right":"-12.25vw","height":"64vh","width":"12.25vw"},200);
                    $(".left_header").animate({"margin-top":"0vw","margin-left":"0vw","height":"64vh","width":"16.75vw"},200);
                    $(".footer").animate({"margin-bottom":"0vh","height":"30vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("nav").animate({"margin-top":"0vh","height":"8vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("#map-canvas").animate({"height":"64vh","width":"83.25vw","margin-left":"16.75vw","margin-top":"8vh"},200);
                    $("#r_controls").animate({"right":"27px","top":"37%"},200);
                    $("#l_controls").animate({"left":"16.75vw","top":"37%"},200);
                    $("#t_controls").animate({"left":"50%","top":"8vh"},200);
                    $("#d_controls").animate({"left":"50%","bottom":h+"px"},200);
                }
                if(t==0 && d==0 && r==1 && l==1){
                    $(".right_header").animate({"margin-top":"0vw","margin-right":"-12.25vw","height":"64vh","width":"12.25vw"},200);
                    $(".left_header").animate({"margin-top":"0vw","margin-left":"-16.75vw","height":"64vh","width":"16.75vw"},200);
                    $(".footer").animate({"margin-bottom":"0vh","height":"30vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("nav").animate({"margin-top":"0vh","height":"8vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("#map-canvas").animate({"height":"64vh","width":"100vw","margin-left":"0vw","margin-top":"8vh"},200);
                    $("#r_controls").animate({"right":"27px","top":"37%"},200);
                    $("#l_controls").animate({"left":"0vw","top":"37%"},200);
                    $("#t_controls").animate({"left":"50%","top":"8vh"},200);
                    $("#d_controls").animate({"left":"50%","bottom":h+"px"},200);
                }

                if(t==0 && d==1 && r==0 && l==0){
                    $(".right_header").animate({"margin-top":"0vw","margin-right":"0vw","height":"92vh","width":"12.25vw"},200);
                    $(".left_header").animate({"margin-top":"0vw","margin-left":"0vw","height":"92vh","width":"16.75vw"},200);
                    $(".footer").animate({"margin-bottom":"-30vh","height":"30vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("nav").animate({"margin-top":"0vh","height":"8vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("#map-canvas").animate({"height":"92vh","width":"71vw","margin-left":"16.75vw","margin-top":"8vh"},200);
                    $('.FixedHeader_Cloned').hide();
                    $("#r_controls").animate({"right":w+"px","top":"50%"},200);
                    $("#l_controls").animate({"left":"16.75vw","top":"50%"},200);
                    $("#t_controls").animate({"left":"50%","top":"8vh"},200);
                    $("#d_controls").animate({"left":"50%","bottom":"30px"},200);
                }

                if(t==0 && d==1 && r==0 && l==1){
                    $(".right_header").animate({"margin-top":"0vw","margin-right":"0vw","height":"92vh","width":"12.25vw"},200);
                    $(".left_header").animate({"margin-top":"0vw","margin-left":"-16.75vw","height":"92vh","width":"16.75vw"},200);
                    $(".footer").animate({"margin-bottom":"-30vh","height":"30vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("nav").animate({"margin-top":"0vh","height":"8vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("#map-canvas").animate({"height":"92vh","width":"87.75vw","margin-left":"0vw","margin-top":"8vh"},200);
                    $('.FixedHeader_Cloned').hide();
                    $("#r_controls").animate({"right":w+"px","top":"50%"},200);
                    $("#l_controls").animate({"left":"0vw","top":"50%"},200);
                    $("#t_controls").animate({"left":"50%","top":"8vh"},200);
                    $("#d_controls").animate({"left":"50%","bottom":"30px"},200);
                }

                if(t==0 && d==1 && r==1 && l==0){
                    $(".right_header").animate({"margin-top":"0vw","margin-right":"-12.25vw","height":"92vh","width":"12.25vw"},200);
                    $(".left_header").animate({"margin-top":"0vw","margin-left":"0vw","height":"92vh","width":"16.75vw"},200);
                    $(".footer").animate({"margin-bottom":"-30vh","height":"30vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("nav").animate({"margin-top":"0vh","height":"8vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("#map-canvas").animate({"height":"92vh","width":"83.25vw","margin-left":"16.75vw","margin-top":"8vh"},200);
                    $('.FixedHeader_Cloned').hide();
                    $("#r_controls").animate({"right":"27px","top":"50%"},200);
                    $("#l_controls").animate({"left":"16.75vw","top":"50%"},200);
                    $("#t_controls").animate({"left":"50%","top":"8vh"},200);
                    $("#d_controls").animate({"left":"50%","bottom":"30px"},200);
                }

                if(t==0 && d==1 && r==1 && l==1){
                    $(".right_header").animate({"margin-top":"0vw","margin-right":"-12.25vw","height":"92vh","width":"12.25vw"},200);
                    $(".left_header").animate({"margin-top":"0vw","margin-left":"-16.75vw","height":"92vh","width":"16.75vw"},200);
                    $(".footer").animate({"margin-bottom":"-30vh","height":"30vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("nav").animate({"margin-top":"0vh","height":"8vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("#map-canvas").animate({"height":"92vh","width":"100vw","margin-left":"0vw","margin-top":"8vh"},200);
                    $('.FixedHeader_Cloned').hide();
                    $("#r_controls").animate({"right":"27px","top":"50%"},200);
                    $("#l_controls").animate({"left":"0","top":"50%"},200);
                    $("#t_controls").animate({"left":"50%","top":"8vh"},200);
                    $("#d_controls").animate({"left":"50%","bottom":"30px"},200);
                }

                if(t==1 && d==0 && r==0 && l==0){
                    $(".right_header").animate({"margin-top":"-3vw","margin-right":"0vw","height":"70vh","width":"12.25vw"},200);
                    $(".left_header").animate({"margin-top":"-3vw","margin-left":"0vw","height":"70vh","width":"16.75vw"},200);
                    $(".footer").animate({"margin-bottom":"0vh","height":"30vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("nav").animate({"margin-top":"-8vh","height":"8vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("#map-canvas").animate({"height":"70vh","width":"71vw","margin-left":"16.75vw","margin-top":"0vh"},200);
                    $("#r_controls").animate({"right":w+"px","top":"37%"},200);
                    $("#l_controls").animate({"left":"16.75vw","top":"37%"},200);
                    $("#t_controls").animate({"left":"50%","top":"0vh"},200);
                    $("#d_controls").animate({"left":"50%","bottom":h+"px"},200);
                }

                if(t==1 && d==0 && r==0 && l==1){
                    $(".right_header").animate({"margin-top":"-3vw","margin-right":"0vw","height":"70vh","width":"12.25vw"},200);
                    $(".left_header").animate({"margin-top":"-3vw","margin-left":"-16.75vw","height":"70vh","width":"16.75vw"},200);
                    $(".footer").animate({"margin-bottom":"0vh","height":"30vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("nav").animate({"margin-top":"-8vh","height":"8vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("#map-canvas").animate({"height":"70vh","width":"87.75vw","margin-left":"0vw","margin-top":"0vh"},200);
                    $("#r_controls").animate({"right":w+"px","top":"37%"},200);
                    $("#l_controls").animate({"left":"0vw","top":"37%"},200);
                    $("#t_controls").animate({"left":"50%","top":"0vh"},200);
                    $("#d_controls").animate({"left":"50%","bottom":h+"px"},200);
                }

                if(t==1 && d==0 && r==1 && l==0){
                    $(".right_header").animate({"margin-top":"-3vw","margin-right":"-12.25vw","height":"70vh","width":"12.25vw"},200);
                    $(".left_header").animate({"margin-top":"-3vw","margin-left":"0vw","height":"70vh","width":"16.75vw"},200);
                    $(".footer").animate({"margin-bottom":"0vh","height":"30vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("nav").animate({"margin-top":"-8vh","height":"8vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("#map-canvas").animate({"height":"70vh","width":"83.25vw","margin-left":"16.75vw","margin-top":"0vh"},200);
                    $("#r_controls").animate({"right":"27px","top":"37%"},200);
                    $("#l_controls").animate({"left":"16.75vw","top":"37%"},200);
                    $("#t_controls").animate({"left":"50%","top":"0vh"},200);
                    $("#d_controls").animate({"left":"50%","bottom":h+"px"},200);
                }

                if(t==1 && d==0 && r==1 && l==1){
                    $(".right_header").animate({"margin-top":"-3vw","margin-right":"-12.25vw","height":"70vh","width":"12.25vw"},200);
                    $(".left_header").animate({"margin-top":"-3vw","margin-left":"-16.75vw","height":"70vh","width":"16.75vw"},200);
                    $(".footer").animate({"margin-bottom":"0vh","height":"30vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("nav").animate({"margin-top":"-8vh","height":"8vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("#map-canvas").animate({"height":"70vh","width":"100vw","margin-left":"0vw","margin-top":"0vh"},200);
                    $("#r_controls").animate({"right":"27px","top":"37%"},200);
                    $("#l_controls").animate({"left":"0vw","top":"37%"},200);
                    $("#t_controls").animate({"left":"50%","top":"0vh"},200);
                    $("#d_controls").animate({"left":"50%","bottom":h+"px"},200);
                }

                if(t==1 && d==1 && r==0 && l==0){
                    $(".right_header").animate({"margin-top":"-3vw","margin-right":"0vw","height":"100vh","width":"12.25vw"},200);
                    $(".left_header").animate({"margin-top":"-3vw","margin-left":"0vw","height":"100vh","width":"16.75vw"},200);
                    $(".footer").animate({"margin-bottom":"-30vh","height":"30vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("nav").animate({"margin-top":"-8vh","height":"8vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("#map-canvas").animate({"height":"100vh","width":"71vw","margin-left":"16.75vw","margin-top":"0vh"},200);
                    $('.FixedHeader_Cloned').hide();
                    $("#r_controls").animate({"right":w+"px","top":"50%"},200);
                    $("#l_controls").animate({"left":"16.75vw","top":"50%"},200);
                    $("#t_controls").animate({"left":"50%","top":"0vh"},200);
                    $("#d_controls").animate({"left":"50%","bottom":"30px"},200);
                }

                if(t==1 && d==1 && r==0 && l==1){
                    $(".right_header").animate({"margin-top":"-3vw","margin-right":"0vw","height":"100vh","width":"12.25vw"},200);
                    $(".left_header").animate({"margin-top":"-3vw","margin-left":"-16.75vw","height":"100vh","width":"16.75vw"},200);
                    $(".footer").animate({"margin-bottom":"-30vh","height":"30vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("nav").animate({"margin-top":"-8vh","height":"8vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("#map-canvas").animate({"height":"100vh","width":"87.75vw","margin-left":"0vw","margin-top":"0vh"},200);
                    $('.FixedHeader_Cloned').hide();
                    $("#r_controls").animate({"right":w+"px","top":"50%"},200);
                    $("#l_controls").animate({"left":"0vw","top":"50%"},200);
                    $("#t_controls").animate({"left":"50%","top":"0vh"},200);
                    $("#d_controls").animate({"left":"50%","bottom":"30px"},200);
                }

                if(t==1 && d==1 && r==1 && l==0){
                    $(".right_header").animate({"margin-top":"-3vw","margin-right":"-12.25vw","height":"100vh","width":"12.25vw"},200);
                    $(".left_header").animate({"margin-top":"-3vw","margin-left":"0vw","height":"100vh","width":"16.75vw"},200);
                    $(".footer").animate({"margin-bottom":"-30vh","height":"30vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("nav").animate({"margin-top":"-8vh","height":"8vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("#map-canvas").animate({"height":"100vh","width":"83.25vw","margin-left":"16.75vw","margin-top":"0vh"},200);
                    $('.FixedHeader_Cloned').hide();
                    $("#r_controls").animate({"right":"27px","top":"50%"},200);
                    $("#l_controls").animate({"left":"16.75vw","top":"50%"},200);
                    $("#t_controls").animate({"left":"50%","top":"0vh"},200);
                    $("#d_controls").animate({"left":"50%","bottom":"30px"},200);
                }

                if(t==1 && d==1 && r==1 && l==1){
                    $(".right_header").animate({"margin-top":"-3vw","margin-right":"-12.25vw","height":"100vh","width":"12.25vw"},200);
                    $(".left_header").animate({"margin-top":"-3vw","margin-left":"-16.75vw","height":"100vh","width":"16.75vw"},200);
                    $(".footer").animate({"margin-bottom":"-30vh","height":"30vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("nav").animate({"margin-top":"-8vh","height":"8vh","width":"100%"},200);
                    $("#map-canvas").animate({"height":"100vh","width":"100vw","margin-left":"0vw","margin-top":"0vh"},200);
                    $('.FixedHeader_Cloned').hide();
                    $("#r_controls").animate({"right":"27px","top":"50%"},200);
                    $("#l_controls").animate({"left":"0vw","top":"50%"},200);
                    $("#t_controls").animate({"left":"50%","top":"0vh"},200);
                    $("#d_controls").animate({"left":"50%","bottom":"30px"},200);
                }

                setTimeout(function () {HomeJS._mapResize();}, 200);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use CSS Media query

see -> https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/04/23/responsive-web-design-layouts-and-media-queries/

Comment: I know media query but current code is in jquery with conditional code.